# MySQL query to get joined table results

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a chance this has been asked but I'm not entirely sure how to word it which makes searching for an answer a bit difficult.

I have a table of accommodation listings (listingid (primary key), listing_name, description, etc..). I then have another table for attributes relating to each listing (attributeid (primary key), listingid, attribute). Each attribute takes up its own row in the table - I realise this could be much smarter but have inherited the data structure.

My example of what I want to achieve is:

```
SELECT all listings where attributes have "WiFi" AND "Air Conditioning" AND "Swimming Pool"
```

Along with these must have attributes, I only want to return listings that match ANY of the following: "Motel", "Hotel", "Apartment".

I was initially doing a INNER JOIN on the attributes table and then going `WHERE (attribute = "X" AND attribute = "Y") AND (attribute = "XX" OR attribute = "YY")` but realised that the start of this statement will never match multiple rows as it is only ever checking against a single row. So need to consider the entire result of the JOIN (or sub query?) which is where I need to expand my SQL understanding.

I don't really want to go down my typical route of creating x amount of sub-queries as I imagine this will make the entire query extremely slow - especially if a user selected a dozen or more attributes to search on.

Hopefully this explains it enough but let me know if you require more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
select
    acc.*
from
    accomodation acc
    join attribute air on acc.id = air.accomodation_id and air.name='Air'
    join attribute pool on acc.id = pool.accomodation_id and pool.name='Pool'
    and acc.type in ('Motel', 'Hotel', 'Appartment')
;
```

Comment: Are you suggesting I do in fact do a table join for every attribute that is being searched on? This could equal 12 or more joins on the same table - is that your intention? I'm fine if that is how it is but just concerned about the time it takes to run the query.

Comment: The joins should be very efficient and quick even for very large tables if there is a foreign key or other appropriate index.

Comment: Yep it initially looks like it works well on my staging site. I'll push it through to the production site tomorrow and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Works like a charm thanks John! And I didn't notice any difference in speed with adding in the extra joins. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
select l.listingid, l.listing_name 
from listings l join attributes a 
on l.listingid = a.listingid
where a.attribute = 'WiFi' 
and a.attribute = 'Air Conditioning' and a.attribute = 'Swimming Pool'
and l.description in ('Motel', 'Hotel', 'Apartment')
```

The column names as per your conditions have been assumed. But this should get you what you need.

Comment: Trouble I found using IN is it only needs to match one of the values rather than all of them. The first part needs to match ALL variables whereas the second part  can match ANY. FYI the second part l.description is also a.attribute as they are also stored as attributes

Comment: modified it with `and` for the first condition